# Solving a specific first order ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the system
$\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{dx}{dt}=4x-2y\\
  \frac{dy}{dt}=5x+2y
 \end{array}
\right.$
From what I understand, we begin with putting this into a matrix:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{dx}{dt} \\
    \frac{dy}{dt}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    4&-2 \\
    5&2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x\\y
\end{bmatrix}
$

We find a matrix such that diagonalizes $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    4&-2 \\
    5&2
\end{bmatrix}$ by finding eigenvectors. However, I am unsure how to continue since we ignore the imaginary part of the solution (correct me if I'm wrong about this) such that there is only one eigenvector $v_1=v_2=(\frac{1}{5},1)$. In fact, I'm unsure I'm even moving in the correct direction.

If I am in the right direction, could someone tell me the next step? If I'm trying to solve this using a incorrect or inefficient method, could someone could point me in the correct direction?

Comment: You find complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors. You will get $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ terms that have cosine and sine terms from the complex eigenvalues (you never ignore those), in this case, $\sin 3t$ and $\cos 3t$ terms. See, for example, http://www.math.vt.edu/people/afkhamis/class_home/notes/F08W11b.pdf (note Euler's Identity)

Comment: Do not ignore the imaginary part.  If you find complex solutions, then the real and imaginary parts of them will also be solutions.

Comment: You have eigenvalues $\lambda = 3\pm 3i \implies e^{3t+3it}, e^{3t-3it}$ are solutions.  Apply Eulers identity. $\mathbf x= Ae^{3t}\cos3t + Be^{3t} \sin 3t$

Comment: As an alternate method to using linear algebra did your instructor/professor tell you that a system of two first-order ODE's can be converted to a single second-order ODE?

Comment: @BobaFret No, but that sounds interesting. could you include a link?

Comment: From the first equation, $x'' = 4 x' - 2 y'$. From the second $y' = 5x + 2 y$. From the first equation, $y = \dfrac{1}{2}(4x - x')$. Substitute and get $x'' = ...$.

Comment: @Moo can you explain why this can be done? what happened to the $dt$?

Comment: When I write $x'$, I mean $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, for example. We can convert a higher order differential equation to a system of first order differential equations and vice-versa, for example, see: http://www.math.poly.edu/courses/ma2132/Notes/MA2132EquationsToSystems.pdf